# Why does adding a new external function increase gas for calls to all other functions?

Tags: solidity, remix, gas, evm

I have added a new external function to my Solidity smart contract.
When checking the gas usage for calls to other already existing external functions, I see the gas usage has increased slightly. Does anyone know why this is? and if the gas increase can be avoided?

Answer (score 2):

As you have not provided any code, I am writing down a possible reason for this.

It's not because of the external visibility. It's because EVM calls the function on a sorting basis.

Let's say you have 3 functions

```
function green() public pure returns (string memory) {
    return "green";
      //costs 750 gas
}

function blue() public pure returns (string memory) {
    return "blue";
    //costs 728 gas

}

function red() public pure returns (string memory) {
    return "red";
    //costs 706 gas
}
```

These functions have their own signatures like this:

```
"ed18f0a7": "blue()",
"f2f1e132": "green()",
"2930cf24": "red()"
```

When we call a function, the EVM iterates through this object and matches the function signature that we provided. And that iteration costs gas.
This iteration happens in ascending order, for example in the above function signatures, if we try to call any of the three functions, the EVM will first check the `red`(2930cf24) function, if it doesn't match the one we called then it will check the `blue`(ed18f0a7) one, and at last the `green`(f2f1e132) function.

With this logic, you can see the gas difference while calling the above functions.
If we remove the `blue` and `red` function from the above code, then the `green` function will cost exactly 706 gas which is equal to what `red` cost before. Because this time EVM didn't have to iterate through 2 more function signatures.

Let me know if this was clear, also share the code and gas differences in case there's any other reason for this.